# C# "linking" classes

Tags: c#, class

I'm starting a simple C# console solution via Mono on Mac OS X.

I have a `Main.cs` file for starters, but I want to create a separate class and be able to access object of that class from my `Main.cs` file.

How can I access that class from the `Main.cs` file?

Say my class name was `Math`.

In my `Main.cs` file, can I create a new object like so:

`Math calculator = new Math()`

Without referencing the class in the `Main.cs` file in any way?

Or, do I have to use some sort of import statement/directive?

Comment: you want to be able to use something without referencing it "in any way"?  How is that possible?  And if so, why?  If you don't mind me asking.....

Comment: @pst OK, thanks.  Why don't you post yours as an answer?  Thanks for the help.  @BeemerGuy, if you didn't get what I meant, I was wondering if I don't have to reference it, or if I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `using` statement if your Main and Math are in different name spaces, otherwise it just works.  Below is an example.  The `using System` brings in the library that contains the `Console` class, but no `using` is required to use the `Math` class.

Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Math caclulator = new Math();
            Console.WriteLine(caclulator.Add(1, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Math.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Math
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios here. Either this class is in a separate dll (class library project), or under the same project. To reference within the same project not additional work is needed, other than referencing it with the correct namespace (as mentioned in other posts).

In the case of a separate dll, you need to add a refence to the project in the project definition. Most default projects come with a reference to `System.dll` and other related libraries. It is recommended to name your dll's based on what namespaces are defined within it. If you have classes like `Foo.Mathematics.IntMath`, `Foo.Mathematics.DblMath` then I suggest you name it `Foo.Mathematics.dll`.

When I was where you are, I picked up **.NET Framework Essentials** from O'Reilly and it had answers to all my questions at the time.